# How can I display HTML file using nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, iframe, module

I am trying to display `sample.html` in an `iframe` inside `index.html`, I want to display `index.html` using [NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/).

When I displayed the `index.html` I can see an empty frame. But when I open that index locally on a browser by double-clicking it works perfectly. What should I do to solve this?

Anyone, please help.

Comment: Node.js isn't a web browser. It has no built-in way to display HTML. I could speculate that you have written a web server using it and are trying to load your pages from it in a browser. Then I could speculate further about what you did wrong. Instead, you should provide a [mcve].

Comment: What is "When I displayed the index.html", do you `console.log('your_content_html')` ?

Comment: var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');
const PORT=8080; 

fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, html) {

    if (err) throw err;    

    http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});        
        response.write(html);  
        response.end();  
    }).listen(PORT);
});

Comment: <iframe id="serviceFrameSend" src="./sample.html"   frameborder="0">                       this is my index.html

Comment: my question is when I use response.write(HTML) it is displaying index.html in the browser. but nothing in the iframe. Do I need to tell the node which all HTML files that I am using?

Answer (score 0):

For that, I have to use express.

Before using any file, We need to use **express.static** to tell the node to use the files.

`var express = require('express');<br>
var app = express();<br>
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/directory_where_html_stored"));`